# Делаю CRUD-проект. Сделал кнопку Update и при вызове метода save у меня работник не обновляется а добавляется новый

Tags: java, mysql, spring, boot, crud

Читал ,что метод save  работает как saveOrUpdate. Но почему-то у меня все время работник  добавляется при  нажатии на кнопку update а не просто обновляется. Вроде все по шаблону делал. В чем может быть проблема? Буду очень благодарен за ответ.

Comment: `id` задан у работника, который приходит в метод save, или там null/0? Лучше добавьте пример кода

Comment: К сожалению не знаю как прикрепить фото кода ..

Comment: сюда не нужно фото кода прикреплять...сюда нужно добавлять код в текстовом виде

Comment: Понял. Вот метод из класса ServiceImpl (у меня не работники а пациенты) @Override 
 public Patient updatePatient(Patient patient) { 
 return patientRepository.save(patient); 
 }

Comment: Вот методы контроллера :"/patients-edit/{id}" 
 public String editPatientForm("id" Long id, Model model){ 
 Patient patient = patientService.findById(id); 
 model.addAttribute("patient", patient); 
 return "/patient-edit"; 
 } 
 "/patient-edit" 
 public String editPatient(Patient patient){ 
 patientService.updatePatient(patient); 
 return "redirect:/patients"; 
 }

Comment: Как этот код отправлять правильно? Его же невозможно читать

Comment: Наверно не правильный метод используется на кнопке, а название можно поменять на add, именно это по смыслу больше подходит для save. Всем может быть проблема это невозможно понять из того что написано в вопросе.

Comment: @RomanC , а как тогда правильно вопрос оформлять ( сегодня зарегистрировался только ) если нельзя фото кода прикрепить ?

Comment: Добавляйте код в текст вопроса, а не комментарием. В редакторе есть возможность отформатировать код https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: @DimaBohnat Фото кода прикрепить можно, но не нужно, это никто не будет смотреть, да и поисковик не может найти. [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ссылка на помощь.